# Truncate the length of a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Given an ordered Python dictionary, what is the most Pythonic way to truncate its length? For example, if I'm given a dictionary with several thousand entries how do I truncate it to be the first 500 entries only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you really to modify the dictionary in-place? You can easily generate a new one (thanks to iterators, without even touching the items you don't need):

```
OrderedDict(itertools.islice(d.iteritems(), 500))  # Python2
OrderedDict(itertools.islice(d.items(), 500))  # Python3
```

You *could* also truncate the original one, but that would be less performant for large one and is propably not needed. Semantics are different if someone else is using `d`, of course.

```
# can't use .iteritems() as you can't/shouldn't modify something while iterating it
to_remove = d.keys()[500:] # slice off first 500 keys
for key in to_remove:
    del d[key]
```

Comment: You could even subclass OrderedDict and implement slicing on it. I'm kind of surprised OrderedDict doesn't have more list-like methods.

Comment: beware that `d.keys()` is not ordered. you should use `to_remove = sorted(d)[500:]` instead (python >= 2.6)

Comment: @mulllhausen `d` is an OrderedDict, and ordered does not mean sorted.

Comment: @delnan ah my bad. i'm new to python, i didn't realise there was a difference between dictionary and ordered-dictionary

Comment: for py3 `OrderedDict(itertools.islice(d.items(), 500))

Answer (score -1):

If the dict is already ordered you can just select the number of elements you need like this

```
dict = json.loads(response.text)
dicts_result = dict['results']

dicts_result = dicts_result[:5] #This gives me 5 elements
```